# How to fix an issue with UIImages not showing up in simulator or iPhone for Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm having an issue with my images not showing up in simulator or iPhone when working with Xcode. The UIImage will show up in the main.storyboard but when I run the app in simulator or on my iPhone everything shows up except the `UIImage`.

What makes this frustrating is that I was able to make the same app work just fine based off a tutorial I did but my own isn't working.

When I ran into this issue, I decided to first close Xcode and then open the project again, that didn't work. Then I decided since it isn't a very hard project to just start from the very beginning and make the app again. That resulted in the same problem, with the app up and running but no UIImages showing up.

I then decided that maybe the problem was based off the number of images I had. The original tutorial app I made only had five images and that ran fine on both simulator and iPhone. My version first had 26 images, but I thought just for the sake of making this work I scaled it back to 5. No luck, still not working.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

I'm not sure if this is related to why the app isn't showing the UIImages but this is what is connected to the UIImage that I pulled into the `main.storyboard`.

```
func newBallImage() {

  randomBallNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ... 4)

  imageView.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[randomBallNumber])

}
```

I also thought that it could be related to my function but I'm scratching my head because this is the exact same code I wrote for the tutorial app and that was working just fine.

EDIT:

I also added these pictures to show that the tutorial app I made shows my UIImage when running in simulator, but for whatever reason it does not appear in my version. The First two images are the tutorial app I made and the second two are my own version that I'm working on.

[The Tutorial I followed and typed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejgs7.png) 
[The Tutorial I followed and typed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQKYz.png)

[My version that I made using the same tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37v7a.png)
[It's not showing up when running the simulator or on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGBmz.png)

Comment: Where are you calling `newBallImage`?

Comment: Hi, I'm still new to all this so I could be mistaken but I wrote this function to change the UIImage to a random image. The function on the tutorial one that I also typed up didn't give me any trouble.

Comment: What other code did the tutorial have (that you probably didn't have)? There should be a line that looks like `newBallImage()`.

Comment: Hi I went ahead and posted the whole code in a screenshot for both the tutorial app I made and my own version. I was looking for a line that looks like newBallImage() and its there for my button, my shake motion, and in my super.viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is showing up in the storyboard, that suggests that it's present in your bundle and you're able to access it properly.

It seems likely that the images are not named what you expect. It has to be an exact match.

Select the image view in your storyboard and check in the attributes inspector - what is the image called?

What are your "millennial" 8-ball images called? What does it show in the asset catalog? These image names have to match the names in your `ballArray`.

Add a breakpoint to this line:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: ballArray[randomBallNumber])
```

If the code pauses, great, your function is being called! Now you need to figure out where it's going wrong. When the code pauses, type this into the debugger:

```
po UIImage(named: ballArray[randomBallNumber])
```

If this says nil, then your image names don't match what is in the array.

Comment: YOO, jrturton you the man! I went back to my to attributes inspector and figured out what was the problem! In my version I named all the images Ball1 with a capital B, which doesn't match the code! Went back in and changed b to B and voila! Now the images are showing up. I didn't think and for future reference will remember that the naming is going to be case sensitive!